# Way to check complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I recently had a friend challange me to solve a question that he saw on a job interview:

> N elements are split into k arrays. Find an algorithm that returns whether any of the elements are identical in (k log N) time.

**Please do not provide an answer, I'd really like to solve it myself.**

The question I have is: Is there a website similar to regexpal to test the complexity of my algorithm? If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how to actually find the complexity?

I have a general idea, but it's been a while since I last tried to do a problem like this.

**Edit: New question to add to this. how does K Log N compare to N log N. Obviously when K is 1 it's just log N, which is more efficient than O(n), but if K >= n it's even worse than N log N, correct?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the complexity of an algorithm function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673576/how-to-determine-the-complexity-of-an-algorithm-function)

Comment: is that even possible? Let k = 1. Can you check for duplicates of N elements in logN time?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible yet, I haven't given it a try!

Comment: That was a rhetorical question. I'm saying there's something wrong with the question. As it already fails on k=1.

Comment: in simple terms, i'm sorry bro, the optimal solution is O(N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: New question to add to this. how does K Log N compare to N log N. Obviously when K is 1 it's just log N, which is more efficient than O(n), but if K >= n it's even worse than N log N, correct?**

To answer your edit, you could use the klogn algorithm when k < n and the nlogn algo when n < k

Answer (score 2):

You usually find the complexity of the algorithm by reasoning and mathematical proof. Running the algorithm on some data won't give you the true complexity (`BigOh` or `Theta`) it'll just give you some estimate on the data that was provided.

Quicksort for instance is *average* `BigOh n log n` but worst case `BigOh n^2`, the worst case happens if you select a bad pivot.

You need to figure out the worst cases yourself and do the analysis I'm afraid. If you need help (or a reminder) doing the analysis a good place to look is YouTube or iTunesU in the computer science category on major US universities (for instance the MIT Introduction to Algorithms).

Comment: Drat. I feared as much, I was hoping there was some hidden web gem that I had missed.

Comment: @Joshua No unfortunately this one is just hard work on the old grey matter